# Is there a way to combine two png images at shader editor?

Tags: materials, shaders, image, compositing-nodes

Is there a some trick to combine two png images at shader editor with same behavior as Alpha Over Node in Compositor.

I am familiar with MixRGB node and the fact that factor can be used to mix colors with alpha mask.

The problem with MixRGB is that there is no a real way to add two images at the top of each other or atleast I haven´t discovered easy way of doing that.

If your suggested node tree would also have a feature to color black and white png images that would be neat.

*Two png images. First I would like to color them, then add them together in side of shader editor. The background color should remain saparated*
[image]

*I am using Blender to design car wraps and this feature could save a lot of time.*
[image]

Comment: of course you can put an image in front of the other with the MixRGB node, you just need to have a transparent background for your font, and plug the alpha output socket of the Image Texture into the factor of the MixRGB

Comment: Ouh, it was that easy... I feel stupid. I always tried to blend the two images with a background color rather than adding them together with alpha mask.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

elaborating on @moonboots comment

[image]

Comment: You don't need the Background color node, color can be set directly in the color mix node

Comment: Thanks, I would have been lost without this image!